# Zend_Form::setElementDecorators $elements param doesn't make a difference

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form, zend-decorators

From the docs ...

> Zend_Form setElementDecorators (
>   $decorators, [ $elements = null],
>   [bool $include = true])
>
> ```
> array $decorators
> array|null $elements: Specific elements to decorate or exclude from decoration
> bool $include: Whether $elements is an inclusion or exclusion list
> ```

I wanted to re-use the same decorators for most of my elements ... but not the submit buttons ... I tried

```
...

$this->addElement('submit', 'btnSubmitProject', array(
  'label' => 'Add Project',
  'ignore' => true
));

$this->setElementDecorators(
  array(
    'ViewHelper',
    'Errors',
    'Label'
  ),
  array(
    'btnSubmitProject', 'submit' // I think I should be using the 1st (btnSubmitProject) but I have 'submit' just to be sure
  ),
  true // and false
);
```

I tried true & false for the `$include` flag. Both does not seem to make a difference. All elements are styled the same, with label

Comment: You don't need to second element in the `$elements` array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$sumbit ->removeDecorator('label');
```